# Why do I need to check if a liquid-fire transition has a newElement?

Tags: ember.js

The [default liquid-fire transition](https://github.com/ember-animation/liquid-fire/blob/f3cbdb539152ee26ee9782a0edbe4b92c6015bc1/addon/transitions/default.js) checks if `this.newElement` exists.

```
import { Promise } from "liquid-fire";

// This is what we run when no animation is asked for. It just sets
// the newly-added element to visible (because we always start them
// out invisible so that transitions can control their initial
// appearance).
export default function defaultTransition() {
  if (this.newElement) {
    this.newElement.css({visibility: ''});
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

When would `this.newElement` not exist? Isn't it a guarantee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it was just a sanity check. If you check the other transitions for eg. Fade it doesnt have that check.

`https://github.com/ember-animation/liquid-fire/blob/f3cbdb539152ee26ee9782a0edbe4b92c6015bc1/addon/transitions/cross-fade.js`